# Is there a special meaning of the / (slash) in the name of the brew?　Or is it just a slash as a string?

Tags: sass, homebrew

https://sass-lang.com/install suggests the following installation method:

> If you use the Homebrew package manager for Mac OS X or Linux, you can
> install Dart Sass by running
>
> ```
> brew install sass/sass/sass
> ```

Is there any special meaning to the `/`? Or is it simply a string of characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The slashes have meaning, they separate the name into three parts. See for example https://docs.brew.sh/Taps:

> If you need a formula to be installed from a particular tap, you can
> use fully qualified names to refer to them.

- The first two parts are assumed to be a GitHub user/org and repo. The repo is prefixed with `homebrew-`, taking us to the tap: https://github.com/sass/homebrew-sass.
- The third is the specific formula to install from that tap, `sass.rb`.

Comment: thank you. So the username is sass and the repo is sass. So you mean this https://github.com/sass/sass?

Comment: No; I included a link to the tap *in the answer*, the `homebrew-` prefix is required on the repo.

Comment: Ah, I see. I understand.