# Returns an error when updating my Homebrew

Tags: git, homebrew

I'm trying to update my Homebrew using `brew update` but it returns the following error:

```
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Error: Fetching /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/jonj/homebrew-old-openssl failed!
fatal: 'origin/master' is not a commit and a branch 'master' cannot be created from it
fatal: invalid upstream 'origin/master'
```

Comment: Is jonj *your* GitHub account by any chance? It doesn't seem to have that repo, you've tapped something (`jonj/old-openssl`, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63533627/3001761) that no longer exists. Try running `brew doctor`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry Im new in homebrew. When I run `brew doctor`, I got this result: `Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.`

Comment: @jonrsharpe Can I just instead remove all tapped?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Just trying to work with different version of PHP, but for some reason after trying every research result, still unlucky to get the perfect answer. Now, I ended up getting homebrew error

Comment: You can untap the one that's (presumably) been removed with `brew untap jonj/old-openssl`, see https://docs.brew.sh/Taps.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Alright, it works. I didn't thought it is easy as that. You can add your answer if you want so I can give you a check :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Error: Fetching /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/jonj/homebrew-old-openssl failed!
```

When you `brew tap <user>/<repo>`, Homebrew will by default clone `github.com/<user>/homebrew-<repo>` into your `Taps` directory, see e.g. [the docs](https://docs.brew.sh/Taps), [Is there a special meaning of the / (slash) in the name of the brew?　Or is it just a slash as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63533548/3001761)

In this case, at some point you did `brew tap jonj/old-openssl`, but [that repo](https://github.com/jonj/homebrew-old-openssl) no longer exists publicly (currently a 404). To remove it, you can run `brew untap jonj/old-openssl`.

Comment: When I try to untap it on my local it gives me an error: `Error: Refusing to untap zifnab/old-openssl because it contains the following installed formulae or casks:
openssl@1.0.2t`

Comment: @nzifnab Then `brew uninstall openssl@1.0.2t` first and try again